# New natural frequency $\omega$ of system of two charges and spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, spring, oscillators

Consider a spring with rest length $l$ and stiffness $k$. This spring has a natural frequency $\omega_0 = \sqrt{k}$. Suppose we put two identical charges $Q$ on each end of the spring. This system will have a new natural frequency $\omega$. I need to approximate this $\omega$, by only considering electrostatic forces. I can make harmonic approximations too.

I'm not sure how to do this. I want to write down the new potential energy of the system. I suppose when the two charges repel each other, they will be a distance $l + x$ apart, where $x$ is the distance from equilibrium. So the total potential energy would be $$ V = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{Q^2}{l+x} + \frac{1}{2} k x^2. $$ But I don't know how to approximate the new $\omega$. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question. How would you get the natural frequency from the potential energy of, say, a mass on a spring?

Comment: I find it odd that people are voting to close this as low-effort homework-like. It seems to me like a very clear example of what a good homework question for this site should be.

Comment: @DavidZ : What is the *specific physics concept* which the OP is asking about? It seems to me the OP is asking "What should I do next to find the answer?" How does that make it any different from the many questions which have been closed with your approval?

Comment: @sammygerbil Actually, on a second look you're right. I was pretty tired 10 hours ago and I guess I misread the question. The original homework problem asks for an approximation of the frequency and the question is simply asking how to approximate the frequency, i.e. how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural frequency of a mass-on-a-spring is $\omega_0=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ where $m$ is the effective mass. For an unloaded spring of mass $M$ this is approximately $m=\frac13M$. Comparing with your spring we see that $m=1$.

We find $\omega_0$ by writing the equation of motion :
$$m\ddot x = -kx $$
and rearranging into the form 
$$\ddot x + \omega_0^2 x = 0$$
Adding the charges to the spring introduces a repulsive term. The eqn of motion becomes
$$m\ddot x = -kx+\frac{C}{(l+x)^2}$$
where $C=\frac{Q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$. The repulsive term can be expanded as :
$$\frac{C}{l^2(1+z)^2} = \frac{C}{l^2}(1-2z+3z^2-4z^3+...)$$
where $z=\frac{x}{l}$.

You can now combine terms in $x$ in the eqn of motion, and ignore those in $x^2$ or higher, on the assumption that $z<<1$, ie $x<<l$. That allows you to identify a new natural frequency. As with the mass-on-a-spring-with-gravity, you get a constant term, which appears as a fixed offset in the oscillatory motion, ie a new equilibrium extension.

Comment: Why did you post an answer if you also voted to close the question? That's rather inconsistent of you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I set $m = 1$. I only have to keep terms of first order. When I do that, I get $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -kx  + \frac{C}{l^2} - \frac{2xc}{l^3}$. But how do I get the new frequency out of this? I want to write it in the form $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \omega^2 x = 0$, with $\omega$ the new frequency, but I still have a constant term $\frac{C}{l^2}$ ?

Comment: The questions you ask are addressed in my answer.

Comment: @DavidZ : Yes, I am being inconsistent. Prompted by your up-voted comment I also had another look at the question and wondered if I was interpreting the policy too strictly. In view of those up-votes it did not seem to me that the question would be closed. I decided to post an answer first then decide what to do with my close vote. Although inconsistent, I decided to leave that vote in place because I was (and remain) in two minds about the issue.

Comment: @sammygerbil OK, well, as long as you're aware that casting a vote to close a question means that you believe it shouldn't be answered in its current form. For the future.